# 2nd sound plays with less integrity?

Tags: android, audio, headset, speakerphone

I want to press the button on the headset, play a sound via the speaker phone, then record a 10 second audio clip. Here is my code:

```
        SoundPool soundPool;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundPoolMap;
        soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
        soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        soundPoolMap.put(SOUND_RECORD_ON,
                soundPool.load(context, R.raw.on, 1));
        soundPoolMap.put(SOUND_RECORD_OFF,
                soundPool.load(context, R.raw.off, 1));

        AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float streamVolumeMax = mAudioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        if (recordStarted == false) {
            try { // start recording
                audioRecorder.start();
                recordStarted = true;
                System.out.println(String.format("recording: %s",
                        recordStarted));

                mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                System.out.println("speaker on");
                soundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(SOUND_RECORD_ON),
                        streamVolumeMax, streamVolumeMax, 1, 0, 1f);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else { // stop recording
            try {
                audioRecorder.stop();
                recordStarted = false;
                System.out.println(String.format("recording: %s",
                        recordStarted));

                mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                System.out.println("speaker on");
                soundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(SOUND_RECORD_ON),
                        streamVolumeMax, streamVolumeMax, 2, 0, 1f);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The first sound plays on speaker fine, with very good integrity. However, when I press the button again to stop recording, the sound is nearly inaudible, despite using the same clip. Here is the logcat trace:

```
ERROR/MediaButtonIntentReceiver(5290): <!> MediaButtonIntentReceiver 52<!> BUTTON PRESSED :D 
WARN/StagefrightRecorder(1466): Target duration (10000000 us) too short to be respected
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [LGE] output devices :2
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [doRouting]new_snd_device=2,mCurSndDevice=-1
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [SKW]do_route_audio_rpc(2, 1, 0)
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [LGE] output devices :2
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [doRouting]new_snd_device=2,mCurSndDevice=2
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [LGE] output devices :2
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [doRouting]new_snd_device=2,mCurSndDevice=2
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [LGE] output devices :2
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [doRouting]new_snd_device=2,mCurSndDevice=-1
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [SKW]do_route_audio_rpc(2, 1, 0)
INFO/System.out(5290): recording: true
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [LGE] output devices :2
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): Routing audio to Speakerphone_conversation
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [doRouting]new_snd_device=7,mCurSndDevice=-1
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [SKW]do_route_audio_rpc(7, 0, 0)
ERROR/AudioService(1586): <!>android.media.AudioService 895<!> [BTUI] [SCO] ### setMode (2)
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [LGE] output devices :2
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): Routing audio to Speakerphone_conversation
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [doRouting]new_snd_device=7,mCurSndDevice=7
INFO/System.out(5290): speaker on
WARN/AudioFlinger(1466): write blocked for 138 msecs, 71 delayed writes, thread 0xce08
ERROR/SUMAN-statusbarpolicy(1665): <!>com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.StatusBarPolicy 1069<!> mServiceState.getRoaming()false
DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(1665): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 8
DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(1665): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=302880 curHPLMN=302220
WARN/KeyCharacterMap(5290): No keyboard for id 0
WARN/KeyCharacterMap(5290): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
ERROR/MediaButtonIntentReceiver(5290): <!> MediaButtonIntentReceiver 52<!> BUTTON PRESSED :D 
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [LGE] output devices :2
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [doRouting]new_snd_device=2,mCurSndDevice=-1
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [SKW]do_route_audio_rpc(2, 0, 0)
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [LGE] output devices :2
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): Routing audio to Speakerphone_conversation
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [doRouting]new_snd_device=7,mCurSndDevice=2
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [SKW]do_route_audio_rpc(7, 0, 0)
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [LGE] output devices :2
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): Routing audio to Speakerphone_conversation
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [doRouting]new_snd_device=7,mCurSndDevice=-1
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [SKW]do_route_audio_rpc(7, 0, 0)
INFO/System.out(5290): recording: false
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [LGE] output devices :2
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): Routing audio to Speakerphone_conversation
ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(1466): [doRouting]new_snd_device=7,mCurSndDevice=7
INFO/System.out(5290): speaker on
```

Does anybody know why this is the case? I know that in the first portion I did not set the speaker phone back to false; if I do, the sound only gets played through the headset. I am suspecting it is the line that says "too short to be respected."
Thank you very much!

--------- UPDATE WITH MEDIAPLAYER CODE -------------

```
    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Log.e(TAG, "BUTTON PRESSED :D ");

        AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        MediaPlayer playOn = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.on);

        if (recordStarted == false) {
            try { // start recording

                audioRecorder.start();
                recordStarted = true;
                System.out.println(String.format("recording: %s",
                        recordStarted));

                mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                System.out.println("speaker on");

                playOn.start();
                System.out.println("playing on tune");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else { // stop recording
            try {
                audioRecorder.stop();
                recordStarted = false;
                System.out.println(String.format("recording: %s",
                        recordStarted));

                playOn.start();
                System.out.println("playing off tune");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                // mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
                // System.out.println("speaker off");
                // mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
            }
        } // end else
    } // end key down action
```

ok used this code to play the sound, but the 2nd sound is still very quiet (same problem as before)... more suggestions? :D

Comment: I actually don't see the point of using SoundPool for this scenario. Use MediaPlayer for playing the sounds. Much more reliable and straight forward. SoundPool is for optimizations needed for games or heavy usage of sounds.

Comment: now i am getting "mediaplyer went away with unhandled events"... can you please see what is wrong with my code?

Comment: ok nevermind, it seems to be the "release" called too soon
weird though, i assumed that it would at least wait until the clip is done playing before it releases the resource...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I wasn't supposed to play music in a BroadcastReceiver (detects the media button) because the music would only last for as long as onReceive is executed. Thus, a service had to be created to play before recording.